# Best type for ID column in Activity Log table

Tags: sql, types

I need to choose a type for ID column in Activity Log table which would look like this:

| ID | Type | UserID |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | User Logged in | UUID1 |
|  | Something happened | UUID2 |

Any thoughts or recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You basically have three choices for an auto-generated id:

- `int` (typically 4 bytes)
- `bigint` (typically 8 bytes)
- universal unique identifier (UUID) of some sort, depending on the database

If you don't expect your table to grow into billions of rows, then use `int`.  If your table can get really big (think millions of inserts per day), then use `bigint`.  Both of these preserve insertion order, which can be quite convenient.

If you want to anonymize the inserts, then use a UUID.  Do note that this takes up more space.  And because the values are not (necessarily) generated in order they can cause table or index fragmentation.

I think it is fair to say that the most typical type would be `int`.  Also note that you may be using a database that has other options.